# Typescript interface default values

Tags: typescript

I have the following interface in TypeScript:

```
interface IX {
    a: string,
    b: any,
    c: AnotherType
}
```

I declare a variable of that type and I initialize all the properties

```
let x: IX = {
    a: 'abc',
    b: null,
    c: null
}
```

Then I assign real values to them in an init function later

```
x.a = 'xyz'
x.b = 123
x.c = new AnotherType()
```

But I don't like having to specify a bunch of default null values for each property when declaring the object when they're going to just be set later to real values. Can I tell the interface to default the properties I don't supply to null? What would let me do this:

```
let x: IX = {
    a: 'abc'
}
```

without getting a compiler error. Right now it tells me

> TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type
>   'IX'.  Property 'b' is missing in type '{}'.

Comment: I've added docs for you : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/lazyObjectLiteralInitialization.html

Comment: IMO, the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35074490/129196 shouldn't be the approach to take. If you can have an object in a state without having all its properties initialized and still be valid, then you should declare those properties as optional as indicated by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43226857/129196. Otherwise we will lose the sole purpose of using typescript (for type safety).

Comment: What is `IX` short for? Code on stack overflow should generally use real variable names.

Answer (score 250, accepted):

> Can I tell the interface to default the properties I don't supply to null? What would let me do this

No. You cannot provide *default values* for interfaces or type aliases as they are compile time only and default values need runtime support

## Alternative

But values that are not specified default to `undefined` in JavaScript runtimes. So you can mark them as optional:

```
interface IX {
  a: string,
  b?: any,
  c?: AnotherType
}
```

And now when you create it you only need to provide `a`:

```
let x: IX = {
    a: 'abc'
};
```

You can provide the values as needed:

```
x.a = 'xyz'
x.b = 123
x.c = new AnotherType()
```

Comment: Thank you , without defining bunch of default values i used to have unable to set value for undefined property

Comment: Using `any` undermines the purpose of *Type*Script. There are other answers without this drawback.

Comment: could any one help me about similar question but using generics. [Here at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54592940/initialized-dynamically-created-object-with-default-values)

Comment: Odd that basarat would go with the 'any' example when, in the link provided, he offers a much better option with 'let foo = {} as Foo;' ('Foo" being an Interface)

Comment: The OP has gone to the trouble of creating a TypeScript interface and is asking for solutions to the boiler plating. Your solution is to forgo Interfaces completely? May as well suggest that skips TypeScript too...

Comment: This will give error with strict mode. Not sure if its the correct way to approach this.

Comment: You edited the answer to just be a copy of Timar's answer. Why not just redirect to his answer?

Comment: "as they are compile time only and default values need runtime support" - can someone explain why this needs to be the case? Why can't compiler just insert the default values during compilation as long as they are constant values known at compile-time?

Comment: @ibayramli I'm sure there is really no need for runtime support. The compiler could emit the default values on type instantiation.

Answer (score 152):

You can't set default values in an interface, but you can accomplish what you want to do by using [optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties):

Simply change the interface to:

```
interface IX {
    a: string,
    b?: any,
    c?: AnotherType
}
```

You can then do:

```
let x: IX = {
    a: 'abc'
}
```

And use your init function to assign default values to `x.b` and `x.c` if those properies are not set.

Comment: In the question it was asked to initialize `x.b` and `x.c` with `null`. When writing `let x = {a: 'abc'}` then `x.b` and `x.c` are `undefined`, so this answer doesn't fully meet the requirements, although it's a smart quick fix.

Comment: @BennyNeugebauer The accepted answer has the same flaw. This is the best answer

Comment: if x is object with default values, then creating final instance object `let a: IX = Object.assign({b:true}, x);` will cause b,c to be optional also in instance object, which may not be desired

Comment: Properties should not be marked "optional" for the convenience of those using the interface. The answer is "no" you cannot "tell the interface to supply defaults" but you can provide a factory method to initialize an instance of an interface.

Comment: Is it possible to check whether an optional property has been set?

Comment: Timar wrote this answer first. basarat just copied it, taking the credits for it. That is unfair. If you concur, you can flag basarat's answer as "Plagiarized content".

Answer (score 107):

While @Timar's answer works perfectly for `null` default values (what was asked for), here another easy solution which allows other default values: Define an option interface as well as an according constant containing the defaults; in the constructor use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to set the `options` member variable

```
interface IXOptions {
    a?: string,
    b?: any,
    c?: number
}

const XDefaults: IXOptions = {
    a: "default",
    b: null,
    c: 1
}

export class ClassX {
    private options: IXOptions;

    constructor(XOptions: IXOptions) {
        this.options = { ...XDefaults, ...XOptions };
    }

    public printOptions(): void {
        console.log(this.options.a);
        console.log(this.options.b);
        console.log(this.options.c);
    }
}
```

Now you can use the class like this:

```
const x = new ClassX({ a: "set" });
x.printOptions();
```

Output:

```
set
null
1
```

Comment: This cant be used as a default solution for every case, But definitely a creative solution for some cases. 

Comment: what if instead of just logging the values I want to use them like const calcvalue = this.options.a * 1000; this would still raise alarm as it can be potentially undefined..

Comment: @ManishRawat You can for example not declare any of the properties as optional, but instead let the constructor take the type `Partial<IXOptions>`. This way TS knows all properties will be present in `this.options`, but none are required in the constructor.

Comment: @Thor84no though the definition of Partial is to make everything optional, that's all it does

Comment: @JacksonHaenchen taking a partial as an argument for a constructor is not the same as returning an object that isn't listed as a partial. The constructor here will assign everything as defaults first and then as the input values if provided. The input values can thus be partial without affecting whether the created object is complete and typesafe.

Comment: This technique doesn't seem to work to well with functions where you want to fill defaults for partial options.  For some reason, TypeScript doesn't seem to detect that the options have been completely filled in that case.

Comment: Ah, but you can work around the problem I mentioned by having another interface (say, IFOptions) where none of the options are optional, and use that for the class' options (for example, private options: IFOptions)... then the spread works and TypeScript is happy.

Answer (score 33):

You can implement the interface with a class, then you can deal with initializing the members in the constructor:

```
class IXClass implements IX {
    a: string;
    b: any;
    c: AnotherType;

    constructor(obj: IX);
    constructor(a: string, b: any, c: AnotherType);
    constructor() {
        if (arguments.length == 1) {
            this.a = arguments[0].a;
            this.b = arguments[0].b;
            this.c = arguments[0].c;
        } else {
            this.a = arguments[0];
            this.b = arguments[1];
            this.c = arguments[2];
        }
    }
}
```

Another approach is to use a factory function:

```
function ixFactory(a: string, b: any, c: AnotherType): IX {
    return {
        a: a,
        b: b,
        c: c
    }
}
```

Then you can simply:

```
var ix: IX = null;
...

ix = new IXClass(...);
// or
ix = ixFactory(...);
```

Answer (score 17):

You can use the `Partial` mapped type as explained in the documentation:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html

In your example, you'll have:

```
interface IX {
    a: string;
    b: any;
    c: AnotherType;
}

let x: Partial<IX> = {
    a: 'abc'
}
```

Comment: if x is object with default values, then creating final instance object `let a: IX = Object.assign({b:true}, x);` will cause error `Partial<IX> cannot be assigned to IX`

Comment: Partial changes the type. `x` no longer implements `IX`, but a partial of `IX`. `Partial` is good for places where every property might be optional, for example with an ORM, where you can pass a partial of an object interface and update only the fields that are defined (as opposed to `undefined` which is what every field of a `Partial` can be). For interfaces that have fields with default values, you can declare object literals implementing those type of interfaces, without having to declare the default values, using the `let x: Partial<IX> = { /* non-default fields */ } as IX` syntax.

Comment: `x` doesn't implement `IX`, but you can still use it to create an object that implements `IX` by using defaults. You need to provide defaults for all required values though, otherwise there's no guarantee of implementing `IX`. E.g. `const defaults: IX = { a: 'default', b: {}, c: new AnotherType() }; const y = { ...defaults, ...x };`

Answer (score 11):

I use the following pattern:

Create utility type `Defaults<T>`:

```
type OptionalKeys<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?: {} extends Pick<T, K> ? K : never }[keyof T];
type Defaults<T> = Required<Pick<T, OptionalKeys<T>>>
```

Declare class with options/defaults:

```
// options passed to class constructor
export interface Options {
    a: string,
    b?: any,
    c?: number
}

// defaults
const defaults: Defaults<Options> = {
    b: null,
    c: 1
};

export class MyClass {
    // all options in class must have values
    options: Required<Options>;

    constructor(options: Options) {
        // merge passed options and defaults
        this.options = Object.assign({}, defaults, options);
    }
}
```

Create class instance:

```
const myClass = new MyClass({
    a: 'hello',
    b: true,
});

console.log(myClass.options);
// { a: 'hello', b: true, c: 1 }
```

Comment: I love this. I have been playing around with types trying to get to this, but failed at it. Would appreciate if you explaiend a bit on the `OptionalKeys<T>` there please!

Answer (score 7):

Default values to an interface are not possible because interfaces only exists at compile time.

### Alternative solution:

You could use a factory method for this which returns an object which implements the XI interface.

### Example:

```
class AnotherType {}

interface IX {
    a: string,
    b: any,
    c: AnotherType | null
}

function makeIX (): IX {
    return {
    a: 'abc',
    b: null,
    c: null
    }
}

const x = makeIX();

x.a = 'xyz';
x.b = 123;
x.c = new AnotherType();
```

The only thing I changed with regard to your example is made the property c both `AnotherType | null`. Which will be necessary to not have any compiler errors (This error was also present in your example were you initialized null to property c).

Comment: You can improve the factory method by accepting an optional Partial<IX> and copying the provided values over via object destructuring _after_ you’ve initialized the default values: `function makeIX(base: Partial<IX> = {}): IX { return {a: 'abc', b: null, c: null, ...base} }`

Answer (score 5):

It's best practice in case you have many parameters to let the user insert only few parameters and not in specific order.

For example, bad practice:

```
foo(a?, b=1, c=99, d=88, e?)
foo(null, null, null, 3)
```

Since you have to supply all the parameters before the one you actually want (d).

Good practice to use is:

```
foo({d=3})
```

The way to do it is through interfaces.
You need to define the parameter as an interface like:

```
interface Arguments {
    a?;
    b?; 
    c?;
    d?;
    e?;
}
```

And define the function like:

```
foo(arguments: Arguments)
```

Now interfaces variables can't get default values, so how do we define default values?

Simple, we define default value for the whole interface:

```
foo({
        a,
        b=1,
        c=99,
        d=88,
        e                    
    }: Arguments)
```

Now if the user pass:

```
foo({d=3})
```

The actual parameters will be:

```
{
    a,
    b=1,
    c=99,
    d=3,
    e                    
}
```

Another option without declaring an interface is:

```
foo({
        a=undefined,
        b=1,
        c=99,
        d=88,
        e=undefined                    
    })
```

**Follow Up:**
In the previous function definition we define defaults for the **fields** of the parameter object, but not default for the **object itself**.
Thus we will get an extraction error (e.g. `Cannot read property 'b' of undefined`) from the following call:

```
foo()
```

There are two possible solutions:

1.

```
const defaultObject = {a=undefined, b=1, c=99, d=88, e=undefined}
function foo({a=defaultObject.a, b=defaultObject.b, c=defaultObject.c, d=defaultObject.d, e=defaultObject.e} = defaultObject)
```

2. 

```
function foo(object = {}) {
    object = { b=1, c=99, d=88, ...object }
    //Continue the function code..
}
```

**Follow Up:**
If you need types & default values (and you don't want to declare an interface), you can write:

```
function foo(params: {a?: string, b?: number, c?: number, d?: number, e?: string}) {
    params = { b:1, c:99, d:88, ...params }
    //Continue the function code..
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled on this while looking for a better way than what I had arrived at. Having read the answers and trying them out I thought it was worth posting what I was doing as the other answers didn't feel as succinct for me. It was important for me to only have to write a short amount of code each time I set up a new interface. I settled on...

Using a custom generic deepCopy function:

```
deepCopy = <T extends {}>(input: any): T => {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(input));
};
```

Define your interface

```
interface IX {
    a: string;
    b: any;
    c: AnotherType;
}
```

... and define the defaults in a separate const.

```
const XDef : IX = {
    a: '',
    b: null,
    c: null,
};
```

Then init like this:

```
let x : IX = deepCopy(XDef);
```

That's all that's needed..

**.. however ..**

If you want to **custom initialise any root element** you can modify the deepCopy function to accept custom default values. The function becomes:

```
deepCopyAssign = <T extends {}>(input: any, rootOverwrites?: any): T => {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({ ...input, ...rootOverwrites }));
};
```

Which can then be called like this instead:

```
let x : IX = deepCopyAssign(XDef, { a:'customInitValue' } );
```

Any other preferred way of deep copy would work. If only a shallow copy is needed then Object.assign would suffice, forgoing the need for the utility `deepCopy` or `deepCopyAssign` function.

```
let x : IX = object.assign({}, XDef, { a:'customInitValue' });
```

**Known Issues**

- It will not deep assign in this guise but it's not too difficult to
  modify `deepCopyAssign` to iterate and check types before assigning.
- Functions and references will be lost by the parse/stringify process.
  I don't need those for my task and neither did the OP.
- Custom init values are not hinted by the IDE or type checked when executed.

Answer (score 3):

Working through this now. Use a `class` instead of an `interface`.

```
class IX {
  a: String = '';
  b?: any;
  c: Cee = new Cee();
}

class Cee {
  c: String = 'c';
  e: String = 'e';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I needed this for a React Component.

You can use the [Nullish Coalescing Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) which will assign a default Value if the left Hand Value is Null or Undefined:

```
interface IX {
    a: string,
    b?: any,
    c?: AnotherType
}

const ixFunction: React.FC<IX> = (props) => {
  console.log(props.b?? "DefaultValue")
}
```

But this only works if you want to use the variable in only one place.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

I have created wrapper over Object.assign to fix typing issues.

```js
export function assign<T>(...args: T[] | Partial<T>[]): T {
  return Object.assign.apply(Object, [{}, ...args]);
}
```

Usage:

env.base.ts

```js
export interface EnvironmentValues {
export interface EnvironmentValues {
  isBrowser: boolean;
  apiURL: string;
}

export const enviromentBaseValues: Partial<EnvironmentValues> = {
  isBrowser: typeof window !== 'undefined',
};

export default enviromentBaseValues;
```

env.dev.ts

```js
import { EnvironmentValues, enviromentBaseValues } from './env.base';
import { assign } from '../utilities';

export const enviromentDevValues: EnvironmentValues = assign<EnvironmentValues>(
  {
    apiURL: '/api',
  },
  enviromentBaseValues
);

export default enviromentDevValues;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use two separate configs. One as the input with optional properties (that will have default values), and another with only the required properties. This can be made convenient with `&` and `Required`:

```
interface DefaultedFuncConfig {
  b?: boolean;
}

interface MandatoryFuncConfig {
  a: boolean;
}

export type FuncConfig = MandatoryFuncConfig & DefaultedFuncConfig;
 
export const func = (config: FuncConfig): Required<FuncConfig> => ({
  b: true,
  ...config
});

// will compile
func({ a: true });
func({ a: true, b: true });

// will error
func({ b: true });
func({});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is depends on the case and the usage. Generally, in TypeScript there are no default values for interfaces.

**If you don't use the default values**
You can declare `x` as:

```
let x: IX | undefined; // declaration: x = undefined
```

Then, in your init function you can set real values:

```
x = {
    a: 'xyz'
    b: 123
    c: new AnotherType()
};
```

In this way, `x` can be undefined or defined - `undefined` represents that the object is uninitialized, without set the default values, if they are unnecessary. This is loggically better than define "garbage".

**If you want to *partially* assign the object:**
You can define the type with optional properties like:

```
interface IX {
    a: string,
    b?: any,
    c?: AnotherType
}
```

In this case you have to set only `a`. The other types are marked with `?` which mean that they are optional and have `undefined` as default value.

Or even

```
let x: Partial<IX> = { ... }
```

Which makes all the fields optional.

*In any case you can use `undefined` as a default value, it is just depends on your use case*.

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a helper method/function that returns the object with default property values, and then the calling code can override the defaults as needed. That's the approach I'm following as I've been faced with the same question in my current project. This way coding the default property value object is a one time affair, and you can reuse this object throughout your entire application.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge 
This is the same as the last answer but a bit tidier.

Lets install merge

```
yarn add -D merge
```

Next lets create an interface with some options. 
We'll place this into 
**./types/index.ts**

```
export interface ExampleOpts {
    opt1: string,
    opt2: string,
    opt3: string,
}
```

Next lets create a set of defaults 
you could put this in the same file, but lets keep the types seperate and place it into 
**./config/index.ts**

```
import { ExampleOpts } from '../types'

// Defaults
export const ExampleOptsDefault : ExampleOpts = {
    opt1: 'default value 1',
    opt2: 'default value 2',
    opt3: 'default value 3',
}
```

Next lets join it all together with a function within 
**./index.ts**

```
import { ExampleOpts } from './types'
import { ExampleOptsDefault } from './config'
import merge from 'merge'

// The ? makes the parameter optional
export function test1(options?: ExampleOpts) {
    // merge tries to load in the defaults first, then options next if it's defined
    const merged_opts: ExampleOpts = merge.recursive(ExampleOptsDefault, options)
    // log the result to the console
    console.log(merged_opts)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use the Pick utility type and choose the properties you wish to set to required.

```
interface IX {
    a: string,
    b: any,
    c: AnotherType
}

let x: Pick<IX, 'a'> = {
    a: 'abc'
}
```

Then when you want to declare the real IX object, you just merge the defaults with new values, like so:

```
const newX: IX = {
    ...x,
    b: 'b',
    c: () => {}
}
```

This answer was taken from "[How To Set Up A TypeScript Interface Default Value?](https://timmousk.com/blog/typescript-interface-default-value/)"