# TypeScript interface default value on string property

Tags: typescript

I have an interface that looks like this

```
export interface IAppSection {
  key: string;
  order: number;
  header: string;
  content: string;
  modifiedAt: string;
  modifiedByEmployeeId: number;
  change: 'added' | 'removed' | 'updated' | 'none';
}
```

What I'd like to do is have `change` default as `none` when the object this interface relates to is stored.

I have tried `change: 'added' | 'removed' | 'updated' | 'none' = 'none'` but this does not work.

I am sure I am doing something wrong here and would really appreciate some feedback on how I can achieve this.

Comment: I don't think, this is possible inside the `interface`. Though you can initialise default value from the implemented class in its `constructor`.

Answer (score 14):

You can't do this with interfaces. Interfaces are completely erased at runtime and can't impact runtime behaviour; this is by design. You can create a class instead and assign a default value to the field, or you can create a function that will assign the defaults.

We could even construct a function that helps us create such functions with defaults:

```
interface IAppSection {
  key: string;
  order: number;
  header: string;
  content: string;
  modifiedAt: string;
  modifiedByEmployeeId: number;
  change: 'added' | 'removed' | 'updated' | 'none';
}

function withDefaults<T>() {
  return function <TDefaults extends Partial<T>>(defs: TDefaults) {
    return function (p: Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, keyof TDefaults>> & Partial<TDefaults>) :T {
      let result: any = p;
      for (let k of Object.keys(defs)) {
        result[k] = result[k] || defs[k];
      }
      return result;
    }
  }
}

const appSection = withDefaults<IAppSection>()({
  change: 'none'
})
```

Comment: But can this method also handle nested object assignment for defaults ?

Comment: Not sure what I am doing wrong, but `withDefaults()()` returns a function for me

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the default value in the interface, only in the implementation.

But by default they are **undefined** which is mostly just fine.

For the 'real' implementation your string union looks good.

See also:
[Typescript interface default values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35074365/typescript-interface-default-values)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to deal with is marking all *IAppSection* values as required, and then use factory methods to create the *IAppSection* objects, inside the factory method you can ensure that all invariants are meet and assign default values for the optional arguments, per instance

```ts
    const createAppSection = (
      key: string,
      order: number,
      header: string,
      content: string,
      modifiedAt: string,
      modifiedByEmployeeId: number,
      change?: 'added' | 'removed' | 'updated' | 'none';
    ) : IAppSection => {
       // perform invariants validations 
       if(!key){
         throw Error('key required');
       }
       return {
         key, order, content, modifiedAt, modifiedByEmployeeId,
         change: change || 'none'
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same question and found the following solution

> Since interfaces only work at compile-time, they cannot be used to set up runtime default values.
> Luckily, TypeScript provides a workaround for this.
> By using the TypeScript pick utility type, we can select properties from an interface and provide default values for them.

```
interface IPerson {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    role: string;
}

type DefaultValues = Pick<IPerson, 'role'>;

const defaultPersonValues: DefaultValues = {
    role: 'guest'
}
```

and finally:

```
const newPerson: PersonWithDefaultsOptional = {
    firstName: 'Tim',
    lastName: 'Mousk'
};

const person: IPerson = {
    ...defaultPersonValues,
    ...newPerson
}
```

for more information read this article: [How To Set Up A TypeScript Interface Default Value?](https://timmousk.com/blog/typescript-interface-default-value/)