# Initialized dynamically created object with default values - Using Generics and Interfaces

Tags: typescript

I need to initialize initial value of 'gDetailDS' object. I cannot create classes instead of interfaces and interfaces don't allow me to set default values.

I have tried using map or other functions to resolve the issue but could not get success. Using map, get the error "_this.gDetailDS.map is not a function".

```
export interface InterfaceA{
    sysSeq: number;
    code: string;
    isUpdate: boolean;
    version: number;
}

export interface InterfaceB{
    sysSeq: number;
    name: string;
    isReserved: boolean;
    isPublic: boolean;
    version: number;
 }


export class DetailComponent<T> extends CoreComponent {
    gDetailDS: any;
    constructor(){
        this.gDetailDS =  <T> new Object; 
    }

}
```

I want to get default values specially for booleans. for instance, after executing this below line,

```
this.gDetailDS =  <InterfaceB> new Object;
```

I should have an object of type InterfaceB with default sets for

```
this.gDetailDS.isReserved has default value "false";
this.gDetailDS.isPublic  has default value "false";
```

Your help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once transpiled to Javascript, your `DetailComponent<T>` has no information about the `T`. So you can not use it directly to get an instance of T.

But, if you can add parameters to your `DetailComponent` constructor, a solution to your problem would be:

```
export class DetailComponent<T> extends CoreComponent {
  gDetailDS: T;
  constructor(newInstance: new () => T){
      this.gDetailDS = new newInstance(); 
  }

}

class InterfaceAImpl implements InterfaceA {
  sysSeq: number;
  code: string;
  isUpdate: boolean;
  version: number;
};

var detailComponent: DetailComponent<InterfaceA> = new DetailComponent<InterfaceA>(InterfaceAImpl);
```

Comment: How could I set default value for isUpdate?

Another point is that, I dont want to create a class for an interface.

Comment: Like types, interfaces have no existance once the code is transpiled into javascript:

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20InterfaceA%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20sysSeq%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20code%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20isUpdate%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20version%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20InterfaceAImpl%20implements%20InterfaceA%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20sysSeq%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20code%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20isUpdate%3A%20boolean%20%3D%20true%3B%20%2F%2F%20Default%20value%20to%20true%0D%0A%20%20version%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: Thats I know buddy, interface does not exist after transpilation. But before transpiling, how could we initialize our interface value.

Comment: You can maybe have a look at the issue below:
[How to use interface and default parameters together?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4819)

I'm not sure we can achieve having default values for interfaces properties without using classes directly (a class that implements the interface) or indirectly (like using a factory that build objects that are the type of your interface).