# using interface to define a new type

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using an interface to define a new type. Is this a correct approach? I do as following:

```
export interface IQuestionnaire {
  DataProcessingID: string;
  Qestions : [{
        SecurityControl :  string,
        securityGoal: string[],
          }]
}
```

Then, to instantiate from it I have to do this:

```
      IQuestions :  IQuestionnaire = {
    DataProcessingID: "",
     Qestions :[{
           SecurityControl :  "",
           securityGoal: [""]
               }]
  };
```

which actually create an empty object which is not what I want; but without this, it raises an error saying, for example, "Cannot read property 'Questions' of undefined". Is my approach wrong to define a new type?

**====EDIT====**
Here is what I did according to your comments:

```
export interface IQuestionnaire {
  DataProcessingID: string;
  Qestions :  Array<Iquestion>
}
interface Iquestion{
        SecurityControl :  string,
        securityGoal: string[],
}
```

and then I go:

```
 IQuestions ={} as IQuestionnaire;
```

Then I yet get this error: *Can not read property 'push' of undefined* . I don't want to initiate them where I define the interface, as it creates an empty object!

Comment: Your interface is `IQuestionAndAnswer`, whereas the object you are trying to instantiate is of `IQuestionnaire`

Comment: my bad, I have put the wrong interface. sorry. I edited the question

Comment: can't you write only `let question:IQuestionnare={}`?

Comment: no, then it says yndefined object

Comment: `DataProcessingID` and `Qestions` are the required members of your `IQuestionnaire`. So you shouldn't initialize it with an empty Object for starters. Also, since `Qestions` is an Array type and you haven't initialized it, but you're trying to push an Object to, it's throwing an error. Please read my answer carefully. :)

Answer (score 2):

You should model your interface this way instead:

```
export interface IQuestionnaire {
  DataProcessingID: string;
  Qestion: Security[];
}

interface Security {
  SecurityControl: string;
  securityGoal: string[];
}
```

The reason being, `Qestion` is in fact an array of objects, and each object consists of the `SecurityControl` and `securityGoal` properties. Anyways, I believe you meant 'Question' rather than 'Qestion'.

And on your component.ts, you can simply initialise the object.

Answer (score 2):

Prefixing `interface` names with `I` is an anti-pattern in TypeScript as mentioned in **[this thread](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/374)**.

Also, since this `interface` will eventually act as a data model for a JSON Object, the properties in the interface should be in *lowerCamelCase* as a convention.

Consider creating your `interface` chain like this:

```
interface Question {
  securityControl: string,
  securityGoal: Array<string>,
}

export interface Questionnaire {
  dataProcessingID: string;
  questions: Array<Question>;
}
```

**EDIT:**

To initialize it, you'll do this:

```
questionnaire: Questionnaire = {
  dataProcessingID: '',
  questions: []
};

questionnaire.questions.push({
  securityControl: "",
  securityGoal: [""]
});
```

Comment: Thank you guys. I have applied this. But yet I get ""Cannot read property 'push' of undefined" which refers to the Question, that is an array of the interface.

Comment: It needs to be initialized. Don't forget to do that.

Comment: yes, I did like : ""        IQuestions ={} as IQuestionnaire;  ""

Comment: I've updated the answer. Please check to see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: You still have to initialize your array in your object, otherwise you can't push to it. So you either make an empty array or you make an array with a question object and set questionaire.questions to the array. After that you can push new object with .push() since the array is not undefined anymore. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to do it like this:

```
interface Foo {
    bar: number
    bas: string
}

let foo = {} as Foo;
foo.bar = 123;
foo.bas = "Hello World";
```

You can read more about object initialization [here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/lazyObjectLiteralInitialization.html) or in [this related stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35074365/typescript-interface-default-values?rq=1).

Combined with the other answers it could look like this:

```
export interface Question {
  securityControl: string,
  securityGoal: string[],
}

export interface Questionnaire {
  dataProcessingID: string;
  questions: Question[];
}

let questionaire = {} as Questionnaire;
questionaire.dataProcessingID = "12345";
questionaire.questions = [];

questionaire.questions.push({
    securityControl: "control"
    securityGoal: ["goal"]
});
```

Comment: instead of the `{} as Question`, you can have all in one statement: `<Question>{ securityControl: ..., securityGoal: ... }`

Comment: This approach forfeits the type safety. It is not actually ensured that all properties will have been set.