# Typescript Angular: Default Set All Class Members to Null if Undefined (not used)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

Is there an easy way to set all values to null in Typescript class, without manually copy and pasting repetitively like this. Want to follow Dry principle (don't repeat yourself). I want all values to be autoset null if not defined.

```
export class PropertySitusAddress {

    primaryPropertyMailingAddressId?:number = null;
    propertyId?:number = null;
    propertySitusAddressId?:number = null;
    addressFormatId?:number = null;
    apn?: string = null;
    owner?: string  = null;
    situsAddress?:string = null;
    primaryMailingAddress?:string = null;   
    streetNumber?: string = null;
    situsFromNumber?: string = null;
    situsThroughNumber?: string = null;
    fractional?: string = null;
    predirectional?: string = null;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'll be using PropertySitusAddress as interface then there cannot be default values for the properties refer  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35074365/typescript-interface-default-values) SO question for other workarounds.

If you make them optional, then anyways these properties would be having undefined as default value.

If these properties are not be used in interface then you can either implement it in the way @DoronG has done or you can do this:-

```
primaryPropertyMailingAddressId: number | null = null;
```

Comment: what is the | vertical bar operator? trying to google it, getting something about pipes, but thats for html

Comment: yeah in html it's used for pipes. here it means your property can be either number or  null . FYI- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types

Comment: hi Anand, accepted answer and gave points, feel free to thumbs up question also, thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your typing is wrong a `?` does not mean the value can be `null` it means it can be `undefined`.

To your question, think about the JavaScript output, you actually want all the fields to be set to `null` so there's no way around assigning it. However, you can shorthand the assignment, tough I'm not sure it would be less typing:

```js
export class PropertySitusAddress {
    primaryPropertyMailingAddressId?: number | null;
    propertyId?: number | null;
    propertySitusAddressId?: number | null;
    addressFormatId?: number | null;
    apn?: string | null;
    owner?: string | null;
    situsAddress?: string | null;
    primaryMailingAddress?: string | null;
    streetNumber?: string | null;
    situsFromNumber?: string | null;
    situsThroughNumber?: string | null;
    fractional?: string | null;
    predirectional?: string | null;

    constructor() {
        this.primaryPropertyMailingAddressId =
            this.propertyId =
            this.propertySitusAddressId =
            this.addressFormatId =
            this.apn =
            this.owner =
            this.situsAddress =
            this.primaryMailingAddress =
            this.streetNumber =
            this.situsFromNumber =
            this.situsThroughNumber =
            this.fractional =
            this.predirectional = null;
    }
}
```

I guess the best suggestion is to use an editor with [multi-cursor functionality (e.g. vscode)](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/tips-and-tricks#_multi-cursor-selection)