# TypeScript provide default values for missing keys of a Type

Tags: typescript

There might be an incredibly obvious answer, but how does one do the following:

```
type testStatus = {
    foo: boolean;
    bar: boolean;
    baz: boolean;
}

const makeDefaults = (o: Partial<testStatus>) => {
   const keys = // array of `testStatus` keys?
   keys.forEach(k => !(k in o) && (o[k] = false)) // provide a default value for missing keys
   return o
}

const obj: Partial<testStatus> = { foo: true, bar: false } 

const defaultedObj = makeDefaults(obj) // { foo: true, bar: false, baz: false }
```

Basically retrieve all the keys from a Type, to loop through?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript interface default values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35074365/typescript-interface-default-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get keys as value from type because type doesn't exist at runtime. If type is simple and has same value type for all its keys as in example - you can create an array of keys first, then create the type from it:

```
const KEYS = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'] as const;

type testStatus = { [K in typeof KEYS[number]]: boolean };

const makeDefaults = (o: Partial<testStatus>) => {
    KEYS.forEach(k => !(k in o) && (o[k] = false))
    return o
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYewdgzgLgBA0gUQJoGUYF4YG0DkAzEEHAGhhwCMBDAJxLKoC8cBdGSiGUSKAbgCg+UAJ4AHAKYwoY6CiiUoAVw6YA3tjgwAlmEmixIPPGQosYBQFtyY6s2YAuGOUIAbMZR0Bffny7QY5ygBrMQARMTxKBWcoZRgAChAHAAUaKE1KZwAeKRk5RQgAPgBKDAKYFT4YKqNUADoCagRKYAALOMDSmABCdq0dEBKAMkH4kCxA1kwI5wgxIqLK6uoxRWp+vg8BX1gQcgArZNT0rJyoWXklMtUYAkTJagUxUipqB2nZmE2fcD8AE3DItExL8APL7DD+IKhAFRGIJfYlAD0iPKN0IDigDyejhobwys2elAYeJmEg8QA)

Answer (score 2):

Types only exist at compile time, so the exact thing you're trying to do is not possible.

A simpler alternative would be something like

```js
type TestStatus = {
    foo: boolean;
    bar: boolean;
    baz: boolean;
}

const defaultTestStatus: TestStatus = {
    foo: false,
    bar: false,
    baz: false
}


const merge = (partialStatus: Partial<TestStatus>): TestStatus => ({
    ...defaultTestStatus,
    ...partialStatus
})
```