# object key not showing when the value is undefined

Tags: typescript, object, null, undefined, key-value

I'm having an object with +20 of properties.

```
  export interface FinancialAccountInputModel { 
               id?: number;
               code?: string;
               ... }
financialAccount: FinancialAccountInputModel = {};
```

Some of these properties are set to a value and some are undefined. The "key" of those properties with no value, are not shown when I `console.log(financialAccount)`! How can I set those not-showing key's value, to `null`?

Comment: This may help: 
`Object.keys(yourObj).forEach( key => yourObj[key] === undefined ? null : yourObj[key] )`

Comment: This still works for those with value! @capchuck

Comment: Wrote as an aswer with example :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const o = {
  undefKey: undefined,
  nullishKey: null,
  valueKey: 1
};

Object.keys(o).forEach(key => {
  const value = o[key];
  o[key] = value === undefined ? null : value;
});

console.log(o);
```

Comment: `export interface FinancialAccountInputModel {
  id?: number;
  code?: string;
...
}` This is my Object and your code doesn't work in my case!

Comment: Okay, but what are you waiting for if these fields in your objects are optional. If they are not passed to object, there is no way to display them.

Comment: The problem is I HAVE TO send them as `null` through API

Comment: @Qiimiia
Then you need a logic for setting default values for these fields. In place when you set id, for example, it must be look like `response.id = idValue || null`, or any other way, because it seems in TS there is [no standard way to set default values to interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35074365/typescript-interface-default-values)

Comment: oh such a bummer! Thanks anyway

Comment: @Qiimiia not sure, maybe it would be good idea to look at Data Transfer Object pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I would take the following steps:

1. loop over the object with a for in loop
2. check for every key,whether the key is falsy
3. If the key is a falsy as it is undefined
4. set the value to null explicitly

```js
for(let key in Obj){
if(!Obj[key]){
    Obj[key] = null;
}
}
```

Plz check once and see if it works for you

Comment: Thanks for your help. This doesn't work on undefined props, this converts `false` values to `null`