# Providing of default props in class components of React + TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript

### Problem

In the below example, it is expected that the value `"DEFAULT"` will be substituted to `optionalPropertyExample` when it has not been specified:

```js
type Properties = Readonly<{
  requiredPropertyExample: string;
  optionalPropertyExample: string;
}>;

class Sample extends React.Component<Properties> {

  private static defaultProps: Partial<Properties> = {
    optionalPropertyExample: "DEFAULT"
  };

  public render(): ReactNode {
    // ✓ No TypeScript errors 
    const optionalPropertyExample: string = this.props.optionalPropertyExample;
    // ...
  }

}
```

But, it we will not specify the `optionalPropertyExample` when using the `Sample` as component:

```
<Sample 
  requiredPropertyExample="Sample"
/>
```

we'll get the error:

> TS2741: Property 'optionalPropertyExample' is missing in type ...'.

Well, it is because the `optionalPropertyExample` is required on `Properties` type.
But will it be the solution if to make it optional?

```js
type Properties = Readonly<{
  requiredPropertyExample: string;
  optionalPropertyExample?: string;
}>;

class Sample extends React.Component<Properties> {

  private static defaultProps: Partial<Properties> = {
    optionalPropertyExample: "DEFAULT"
  };


  public render(): ReactNode {
    
    const optionalPropertyExample: string = this.props.optionalPropertyExample;
   // ...

  }

}
```

Now, we'll get the error

> TS2322: Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.   Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

in the `render` method. Yes, thanks to `defaultProps` the `this.props.optionalPropertyExample` will not be `undefined` but the problem is how to assure the TypeScript! Without `any`, `variable!` and other type safety cracks, off course.

### Unacceptable solutions

#### Just use the Hooks API!

This question is focused on class components.
The ones who are fine with hooks API hardly will read this topics.

#### Substitute the value on decomposing of the object

Easy, but not scalable. Assume that we have N methods `method1`, `method2` ... `methodN` using  `optionalPropertyExample`  where N is the arbitrary large number.

```js
type Properties = Readonly<{
  requiredPropertyExample: string;
  optionalPropertyExample?: string;
}>;

class Sample extends React.Component<Properties> {

  private static defaultProps: Required<Pick<Properties, "optionalPropertyExample">> = {
    optionalPropertyExample: "DEFAULT"
  };


  private method1(): ReactNode {
    const optionalPropertyExample: string = this.props.optionalPropertyExample ?? "DEFAULT";
    // ...
  }

  private method2(): ReactNode {
    const optionalPropertyExample: string = this.props.optionalPropertyExample ?? "DEFAULT";
    // ...
  }

  //

  private methodN(): ReactNode {
    const optionalPropertyExample: string = this.props.optionalPropertyExample ?? "DEFAULT";
    // ...
  }


  public render(): ReactNode {
    
    const optionalPropertyExample: string = this.props.optionalPropertyExample;

  }

}
```

Now, we want to change the default value of `optionalPropertyExample`.
We need to find all `"DEFAULT"` occurrences in the code and replace it.
There is the risk to forget one of more occurrences or mix up something related.

Maybe we should refer to `defaultProps`?

```js
type Properties = Readonly<{
  requiredPropertyExample: string;
  optionalPropertyExample?: string;
}>;

class Sample extends React.Component<Properties> {

  private static defaultProps: Required<Pick<Properties, "optionalPropertyExample">> = {
    optionalPropertyExample: "DEFAULT"
  };


  private method1(): ReactNode {
    const optionalPropertyExample: string = this.props.optionalPropertyExample ?? Sample.defaultProps.optionalPropertyExample;
    // ...
  }

  private method2(): ReactNode {
    const optionalPropertyExample: string = this.props.optionalPropertyExample ?? Sample.defaultProps.optionalPropertyExample;
    // ...
  }

  //

  private methodN(): ReactNode {
    const optionalPropertyExample: string = this.props.optionalPropertyExample ?? Sample.defaultProps.optionalPropertyExample;
    // ...
  }


  public render(): ReactNode {
    
    const optionalPropertyExample: string = this.props.optionalPropertyExample ?? Sample.defaultProps.optionalPropertyExample;

  }

}
```

Is it best that possible?

Comment: I wouldn’t make the default props `private` and you can’t access `static` fields with `this`.

Comment: @morganney, Oh, sorry about `this`, my mistake. About access modifiers: are we need to access to `defaultProps` externally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TypeScript has supported `defaultProps` since version 3.0.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#support-for-defaultprops-in-jsx) For it to work properly, follow these rules:

1. **DON’T** declare the `defaultProps` field as `private`; if you do, the TypeScript compiler won’t use the field. Instead, declare the field as `public`, or just omit the access modifier:

   ```
   static defaultProps = { // public, not private
     optionalPropertyExample: "DEFAULT"
   } satisfies Partial<Properties>; // TypeScript 4.9 and later
   ```
2. **DON’T** specify `Partial<Properties>` as the type of `defaultProps`; if you do, all properties become optional, making it valid to write `<Sample />` without a value for `requiredPropertyExample`. Instead, use the `satisfies` operator as shown above, or if you’re using TypeScript 4.8 or earlier, one of these alternatives:

   - Specify `Pick<Properties, "optionalPropertyExample">` as the type of `defaultProps`, where the second generic argument is the union of all properties in `defaultProps`. This option enables full type checking but requires some redundant code.
   - Just omit the type annotation. This option is simplest, but unfortunately doesn’t catch misspelled property names in `defaultProps`.
3. **DON’T** mark properties with default values as optional:

   ```
   type Properties = Readonly<{
     requiredPropertyExample: string;
     optionalPropertyExample: string; // no '?'
   }>;
   ```

   Side note: The usual way to declare a props type is to use `interface` instead of `type`:

   ```
   interface Properties {
     requiredPropertyExample: string;
     optionalPropertyExample: string;
   }
   ```

   Inside a React component, `this.props` will automatically be `readonly`.

Here’s a complete working example:

```
import * as React from "react";

interface Properties {
    requiredPropertyExample: string;
    optionalPropertyExample: string;
}

export class Sample extends React.Component<Properties> {
    static defaultProps = {
        optionalPropertyExample: "DEFAULT",
    } satisfies Partial<Properties>; // TypeScript 4.9 and later

    render(): React.ReactNode {
        const optionalPropertyExample: string = this.props.optionalPropertyExample;
        // ...
    }
}

export class App extends React.Component {
    render(): React.ReactNode {
        return <Sample requiredPropertyExample="" />;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I sorry, but in my environment in does not work ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCBJh.png), [code](https://pastebin.com/Qw2aiA1G)). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Don't mark properties with default values as optional. (That is, omit the `?`.)

Comment: But will it not cause the error `TS2741: Property 'optionalPropertyExample' is missing in type ...'.` error when trying to use the `Sample` component in JSX?

Comment: No, it won't. The example I provided (where `App` uses `Sample`) compiles without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are telling `TypeScript` that `optionalPropertyExample` is required. Change following lines:

```
type Properties = Readonly<{
  requiredPropertyExample: string;
  optionalPropertyExample?: string; // note the ? which tells typescript that this is optional
}>;
```

Following portion of your code should set the default value when the `optionalPropertyExample` is not provided.

```
private static defaultProps: Required<Pick<Properties, "optionalPropertyExample">> = {
    optionalPropertyExample: "DEFAULT"
  };
```

Update:
As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35074365/9640177) "Corresponding changes to add LibraryManagedAttributes definition to the JSX namespace in @types/React are still needed. Keep in mind that there are some limitations."

I think the error should go away with latest versions of TS and `@types/React` when the necessary changes are made to the `@types/React`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. "You are getting this error because ..." - I am sorry, but what is the difference between your listing and my second listing (after "...if to make it optional?")? The problem is how to tell TypeScript that `optionalPropertyExample` is non-undefined *iside* the class component. Would you please to guide how to do it?

Comment: ? in type definition means that it is optional property

Comment: In JS if a filed does not exist on object, say `a = {b:1}`, and you try to access `a.c`, you will get undefined.

Comment: "? in type definition means that it is optional property" - I know. However, it always existing because it has the default value defined in `defaultProps`, right? Now, how to say TypeScript that `optionalPropertyExample` is always non-undefined while there is no need to specify it explicitly when using the `Sample` component?