# Building an object of an interface in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an Interface `Person` and I am able to create an object `user1` of the type `Person` by assigning all the properties at once

```
export interface person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  city: string;

}

let user1: person = {
    name:"ron",
    age: 22,
    city:"AL"
}
```

Is there a way for me to build this object instead of assigning all the properties at once. Im am looking for something like this

```
let user2:person;

user2.age = 22;
user2.name = "Dave";
user2.city = "NY"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript interface default values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35074365/typescript-interface-default-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the type utility [`Partial<Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) when initializing the value to indicate that the properties have not yet been defined:

```ts
let user: Partial<Person> = {};
```

After initializing the property values, TypeScript will correctly infer that they do indeed exist:

```ts
user.age = 22;
user.name = "Dave";
user.city = "NY";

const doubleAge = user.age * 2; // Ok
const lowercaseCity = user.city.toLowerCase(); // Ok
const uppercaseName = user.name.toUpperCase(); // Ok
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQAkCHALYQBcyGYUoA5gNzFwNXIgCuZARtCyIJgYAJ7Va9EMwIBfAgQA2EMMi4Zo1VHChhgcRQB50UbCAB8yALz5ZLAuugA6NihsAmdy0dQnpCtbIAEQAInAAbhBB3hq+wmKBQQByAJrRCgg4tMgAJlhcvMoAguyBPi6lAFTIXsgA9HXIAPIA1gSZINmKWADu0AhwGgDCIqJlsU7xok5gWAAyvdBDgxAAFACUTPWNre1ZqlwADof9K0nkbmoT-hAzWACqx0srG1sNzW1AA)

However, if you do not initialize one of the property values, TypeScript will emit an error diagnostic when trying to use it:

```ts
let user: Partial<Person> = {};

user.age = 22;

const doubleAge = user.age * 2; // Ok

const lowercaseCity = user.city.toLowerCase(); /* Error
                      ~~~~~~~~~
'user.city' is possibly 'undefined'.(18048) */

const uppercaseName = user.name.toUpperCase(); /* Error
                      ~~~~~~~~~
'user.name' is possibly 'undefined'.(18048) */
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQAkCHALYQBcyGYUoA5gNzFwNXIgCuZARtCyIJgYAJ7Va9EMwIBfAgQA2EMMi4Zo1VHChhgcRQB50UbCAB8yALz5ZLAuugA6NihsAmd-YQ5ayACZYXLzKAILs1moaUC4RAFTIXsgA9MnIAPIA1go+IH6KWADu0AhwGgDCIqKRjjHCYk5gWAAyRdDlZRAAFACUTCkJAKJQUFhQBMiTU9Mzs8gAfotLSwQA5LVO9aKryMAYyAAOWBgYwCHV6yD+EDCgEP6rTl0AjAAcAAwALK89yHHJOV8qi4BwOJU6ADlyG4os5SBRGlgAKqg9qdXr9ZJDEZjCZzfGzZZEtYbeEQHZ7Q7HU7nZCXa63ED3R4vD7fX7-AhAA)

There are still some scenarios where the inference isn't enough — for example, when the value needs to be used as an argument to a function which requires a `Person`:

```ts
declare function doSomethingWithPerson(person: Person): void;

let user: Partial<Person> = {};

user.age = 22;
user.name = "Dave";
user.city = "NY";

doSomethingWithPerson(user); /* Error
                      ~~~~
Argument of type 'Partial<Person>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Person'.
  Property 'name' is optional in type 'Partial<Person>' but required in type 'Person'.(2345) */
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQAkCHALYQBcyGYUoA5gNzFwNXIgCuZARtCyIJgYAJ7Va9EMwIBfAgQAmEBABs4UFDC4gEYYDmSKsAZSwUwAC0YB1EZfRRsIABQAHTDmqPnASmoAbljAiiwEqhBgyFwY0N4a+nCqADw+OAB8yAC8+LJhMdAAdGwoOQBMZSwFUIWkFNnIAEQAInABEI1VsTXCYg2NAHIAmp0KxmYW1tJ2Vmmu1b5MyAD0AFTIAKJQUFhQBMgHh0fHJ8gAfhdnBACCUAw8EODIWDDIYh7IAOSoCcBJqZ4QOlPshgBhOFgonAMBhgAxSLwIm8sMg3BpyJFoM9Xu8UN9AZ9Cvs0DsPFA+p86hAQWDnm59DgkqDcLivj9yX8UnNgcheFwopoAI5cYCaRTMt6iD74pw4QkuMoAZgALABWXzIVbLAhAA)

In these cases, you can create a function called a [*type guard*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) which will check at runtime to ensure that the type meets the stated expectations. A user-defined type guard is a function whose return type is a *type predicate*:

```ts
function isPerson<T extends Record<PropertyKey, unknown>>(
  p: T,
): p is T & Person {
  return (
    typeof p.age === "number" &&
    typeof p.city === "string" &&
    typeof p.name === "string"
  );
}
```

> See also in the handbook: [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)

Then you can check whether `user` actually meets the definition of `Person` before using it in order to avoid errors:

```ts
let user: Partial<Person> = {};

user.age = 22;
user.name = "Dave";
user.city = "NY";

if (isPerson(user)) {
  doSomethingWithPerson(user); // Ok
} else {
  // Handle the other case here
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQAkCHALYQBcyGYUoA5gNzFwNXIgCuZARtCyIJgYAJ7Va9EMwIBfAgRhcQCMMBzJgGdFGwgAPABVkEAB6QQAEwzIAShARYol-aihYADtDEBpCKIAaZGUAaxAsAHcQAD5ogApiD2pDAIIASmoPTRtjADI0TA1CIigIMC4oXASiIjEvLBhkDwA6NhQAXk7kACJuPmhu5Fzc4lrResaW4TFkTvaeyUZB4dG6iAam5tIKWa7uxelu4jSWeQJLBwAbOFLkJRU1DUssAGUsCjAAC0YAdRFPnR6OJeXQ4aiAnAZZAANywwEsLAIlzKwQw0HBNzUcEurkKMVm+FkiK4aKgrXYBIATJSWCToFtyB0egARODQiDdWmk5rTUQE7oAOQAmpyFMBGnEtBCQHE6VA0ml8MRnm8Pt9pH8vtLZaSTsgAPT65AAeRCchMlzRSqIhuQAAk4FZkcgvigsK6oMgEHArZ9oBA5AQgA)

Answer (score 1):

If you create a class that implements the interface you can set the default value of the properties to be empty

```
class Class implements Person {
  name: string = "";
  age: number = 0;
  city: string = "";
}
```

and then set them as you want later

Answer (score 0):

One way around this is to declare an object with "empty" properties and then initialize them afterwards

```
export interface person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  city: string;

}


let user2:person = {
    name:"",
    age:-1,
    city:""
};

user2.age = 22;
user2.name = "Dave";
user2.city = "NY"
```